# How to convert a MATLAB plot in 3d to a binary image?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, matlab-figure, binary-image

I use `trisurf` for plotting a convex hull. I need to convert it to binary image for using "Geometric measures in 2D/3D images" for calculating "Minkowski functionals" but I don't know how to convert.

[image]

Comment: 3D to a binary image is not a lot to go on.  What have you tried? Do you have an example image and expected output? We aren't mindreaders. Learn [ask].

Comment: i have some scattered points i plotted convex hull by using "trisurf" function. now i wanna convert this figure to binary image because the next code's input is binary image

Comment: So do you want to convert the resulting figure in binary? I am still unclear.

Comment: yes , the resulting figure to binary image

Answer (score 0):

Create regular grid with the right scale using [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html?s_tid=doc_ta) and then use one of the already written codes to check if the points you generated are in the convex hull such as [inchull](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50569-inchull-in-convex-hull) or [inhull](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10226-inhull)

Comment: the package i wanna use , need binary image as input. so how creating mesh could help me?

Comment: Sorry, I meant regular grid. That is basically the ijk values for all the points in the grid. The method used is called `meshgrid`

Comment: yes but after that i should convert the resulting figure to binary image .

Comment: the results should be a 3D true or false matrix (i.e. binary image).